# Angularjs ng-repeat filter based on json value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have a plunker here - http://plnkr.co/edit/AmoiJi8k000OKA6TNdcz?p=preview

I'm using dummy json here - http://myjson.com/4aqlh

I want to display the json content in different parts of the page based on a value in the json

So the stories with a value of Section: "New" will be displayed in one div and 'Old' in another.

This works in the first div where 'New' is dispalyed but in the second div that should only display 'Old', it displays all the stories.

Is there something wrong with the filter or is something to do with the order Angular builds the page.

```
        <div class="container" data-ng-controller="myCtrl">

            <div class="row">

                <div  class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="story" data-ng-repeat="story in stories | filter: story.Section='New' " >
                        {{story.Title}}
                        {{story.Section}}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div  class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="story" data-ng-repeat="story in stories | filter: story.Section='Old' ">
                        {{story.Title}}
                        {{story.Section}}
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: If you cannot find a solution you can always add an `ng-if` filtering the desired objects.

Comment: Hmm...it seems very weird

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you do filtering with `filter`

```
            <div  class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="story" data-ng-repeat="story in stories | filter: {Section:'New'}" >
                    {{story.Title}}
                    {{story.Section}}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div  class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="story" data-ng-repeat="story in stories | filter: {Section:'Old'}">
                    {{story.Title}}
                    {{story.Section}}
                </div>
            </div>
```

It takes an object syntax. `=` is an assignment operator. See [filter documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Answer (score 1):

Specify the expression in the filter explicitly and it will work.

Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/yLIO14rlWdCFKtmg3b3N?p=preview

```
<div class="container" data-ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div class="row">

        <div  class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="story" data-ng-repeat="story in stories | filter: story: story.Section='New' " >
                {{story.Title}}
                {{story.Section}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div  class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="story" data-ng-repeat="story in stories | filter: story: story.Section='Old' ">
                {{story.Title}}
                {{story.Section}}
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```